# update all selects in a column in html

Tags: javascript, html

I have a table where one column is selects. The same options but `selected` could vary. I want to have a button update selects where the options will be updated but

- the selected option will stay the same
- options will be sorted
- the whole page will not refresh
- want to use pure javascript only

I don't know how to

- loop all selects inside one column
- loop all options inside one select
- insert new option in the right (sorted) spot

[working table example here](http://jsfiddle.net/radek/RNJ4S/) or below

```
<html>
<body>

<table id="t0" border="1">
<tr><td>Cars<input type="button" value="update selects" onClick="update_selects;"></td></tr>

<tr>
<td><select name="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat" >Fiat</option>
<option value="skoda" selected="selected">Skoda</option>
</select></td>

</tr>
<tr>
<td><select name="cars">
<option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
<option value="saab">Saab</option>
<option value="fiat" selected="selected">Fiat</option>
<option value="skoda">Skoda</option>
</select></td>
</tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are asking for a number of things, so best to break the problem down and create functions to do each part. To get all the select elements from a particular column in a table:

```
// Return an array of the select elements in 
// a column of a table
function getSelectsInColumn(table, colIndex) {
  var rows = table.rows; // rows collection
  var selects = [];      // for references to select elements
  var s, cell;

  for (var i=0, iLen=rows.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    cell = rows[i].getElementsByTagName('td')[colIndex];

    if (cell) {
      s = cell.getElementsByTagName('select');
      for (var j=0, jLen=s.length; j<jLen; j++) {
        selects.push(s[j]);
      }
    }
  }
  return selects;
}
```

You don't say how the new options will be created or added, but it is pretty simple to add a new option using something like:

```
select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(text, value);
```

That will add an option at the bottom and not change the currently selected option. It uses the old DOM 0 method as that is the most reliable and robust way to do it.

To sort options, the usual strategy is to put the text into an array and at the same time create an object with the option text as property keys and references to the options as values. Always append an extra value to ensure property names are unique (this value is only used as a key, the extra value just ensures uniqueness and shouldn't affect sort order).

Then sort the array and use it to re-order the options, e.g.

```
// Sort options of a select, keep
// selected option selected
function sortOptions(selectElement) {
  var textArray = []; 
  var optionsObj = {};
  var opts = selectElement.options;
  var o, t;

  // Use a clone to move options to - needed as IE
  // doesn't like to shift them in place
  var sortedSelect = selectElement.cloneNode(false);
  var selectedOpt;

  for (var i=0, iLen=opts.length; i<iLen; i++) {
    o = opts[i];
    t = o.text + '-' + i;
    textArray.push(t);
    optionsObj[t] = o;

    // Remember selected option
    if (o.selected) {
      selectedOpt = o;
    }
  }

  // Simple sort
  textArray.sort();

  // Move options to cloned select in order
  for (var j=0, jLen=textArray.length; j<jLen; j++) {
    sortedSelect.appendChild(optionsObj[textArray[j]]);
  }

  // Replace original select with cloned select that has
  // options in order
  selectElement.parentNode.replaceChild(sortedSelect, selectElement);

  // Restore selected option
  selectedOpt.selected = true;
}
```

The last thing is a function that ties the above together:

```
function sortSelects(table, colIndex) {
  var selects = getSelectsInColumn(table, colIndex);
  for (var i=0, iLen=selects.length; i<iLen; i++) {

    // add extra options here before sorting
    // ...

    // Now sort
    sortOptions(selects[i]);
  }
}
```

The above uses basic DOM stuff and is tested in Firefox and IE, so should be OK pretty much everywhere.

To kick it off, call sortSelects with a reference to a table and the column index (noting that columns are zero indexed, so the first is 0, the second 1 and so on):

```
sortSelects(document.getElementById('t0'),0)
```

Comment: thank you @Rob, trying to understand your code.... selects in the first function is an array where every element contain the "whole select". Is that right? Could you give me an example how to call any of your functions where one of the parameters is `table`? What should I replace `table` with?

Comment: I've added some comments to the code and extra explanation. Yes, selects is an array of *references* to select elements. The table parameter is a reference to a table element, like the result of getElementById(tableId)

Comment: @Rob: works! :-) thank you. Do you want to updated `select.options[select.options.length] = new Option(text, value);`? You use everywhere `selects` not select

Comment: one more question: if I display page html code after adding new option I will not see that new option in the code. Only the original ones. Any explanation?